# dynamically set what is included in function call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm working with Boto3 for AWS for my current project. I need to have a few different describe_images arguments for EC2 as optional and I can't use wildcard or empty inputs to get around having them in or not. I'm looking for a way for add arguments being passed as needed rather than having to do a number of `if` checks with slightly different content.

For example, take the snippet below. I'd like for the `Owners` and `ImageIds` arguments to be dynamically added if they are provided upstream but not include them if they aren't. I haven't had any luck with Google yet so figured I would ask make a quick post.

```
response = ec2.describe_images(
    ExecutableUsers=['all'],
    Filters=search_filters,
    Owners=['309956199498'],
    ImageIds=['ami-26ebbc5c']
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [signature of describe_images](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images), you'll see that it accepts the arguments in the form of keyword args (commonly referred to as `kwargs`). With that signature and a bit of [reading on expansion of iterables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters), you can dynamically build up the keyword args that you want to pass to the `describe_images` call.

Here's a very simple example below of a function with the same signature that just echoes the keyword args it gets to give you insight into what the function call is actually receiving.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
     print(kwargs)

owners = None
image_ids = None
search_filters=['a', 'b']

describe_kwargs = {'ExecutableUsers':['all'], 'Filters':search_filters}
foo(**describe_kwargs)

# Now include image ids
describe_kwargs['ImageIds'] = ['ami-26ebbc5c']
foo(**describe_kwargs)

# Now include owners
describe_kwargs['Owners'] = ['309956199498']
foo(**describe_kwargs)
```

If you run this snippet, you'll see the following:

```
{'ExecutableUsers': ['all'], 'Filters': ['a', 'b']}
{'ExecutableUsers': ['all'], 'Filters': ['a', 'b'], 'ImageIds': ['ami-26ebbc5c']}
{'ExecutableUsers': ['all'], 'Filters': ['a', 'b'], 'ImageIds': ['ami-26ebbc5c'], 'Owners': ['309956199498']}
```

In your case, it sounds like you'd want to conditionally update the `describe_kwargs` dict with each of the `Owners` and `ImageIds` keys, based on whether "they are provided upstream".

Comment: I was able to get it working with your input. Thanks a lot! I appreciate the assist.